# how to use v8 shared library in linux

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, v8, embedding, embedded-v8

I am working on a project that uses v8 engine. I have followed the instructions on v8 git page to compile it and generated some .so files. But now after that there are no more directions as how to proceed with those library files. I wanted to try out with the hello-world example provided but it uses static libraries(but we need dynamic ones). I couldn't find any relavant documentation nor tutorials on internet...
Could anyone point me to some directions as how to proceed to include those dynamic libraries to my program..

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial helped me a lot:

https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-build-v8-on-windows-and-not-go-mad-6347c69aacd4

and also, if you don't want to have this kind of problem with the libraries, you can use the v8 NuGet:

https://github.com/pmed/v8-nuget

You can install directly into your project in VisualStudio and you don't need to make any reference.